# Laravel 8 problem during migration creation

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-8

I have an error when I run my migration.

> SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name
> 'binom_id' (SQL: alter table `profs` add `binom_id` int unsigned null,
> add `note_id` int unsigned null)

**Migration**

```
class CreateProfsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profs');

        Schema::create('profs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nom')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('binom_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('note_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profs');
    }
}
```

---

Migration related to the foreign key.

```
class Pprof extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('profs', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->integer('binom_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('binom_id')->references('id')->on('binomes')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('note_id')->unsigned()->nullable();         
            $table->foreign('note_id')->references('id')->on('notes')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {   
        Schema::table('profs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            Schema::dropColumn('binom_id');
            $table->dropForeign('binom_id');
            Schema::dropColumn('note_id');
            $table->dropForeign('note_id');
       Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Pprof` migration is trying to add another column with the name `binom_id` to the `profs` table when it has already been added in your `CreateProfsTable` migration. Removing that line will solve the error.

So in `Pprof` migration, remove:

```php
$table->integer('binom_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

You will also get an error for your `note_id` column as that is defined twice too, so the same applies, remove the following from the `Pprof` migration:

```php
 $table->integer('note_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Alternatively, just combine your two migrations:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('profs');

    Schema::create('profs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('nom')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('binom_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('note_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    
        $table->foreign('binom_id')->references('id')->on('binomes')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('note_id')->references('id')->on('notes')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```